# Yet another small ad CSS bug

Tags: bug, status-declined, advertising, design, amazon

I accessed the site with Internet Explorer 7 from my university today,  just to see how it looked for unregistered users.

I came [upon this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423823/whats-your-favorite-programmer-ignorance-pet-peeve):

[image: Programmer ignorance pet peeves]

Not short of the irony of the ad, look at the starts.

> `Internet Explorer 7.0.5730 on Windows XP SP2`

<sub>I won't make any more ads questions, I swear!</sub>

Comment: This (re-)raises an interesting question: at what point does browser market share become so low that "too localized" is justified?

Comment: Less than 5% of the market.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, Internet Explorer 7 is [explicitly unsupported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71208/167443), so issues you find with it will not be addressed. Hopefully your university has upgraded by now, or at least has some more modern alternatives available.

Comment: Correct, this is why it's declined.

Comment: That's versionist. A discrimination suit is underway.

Comment: @Jim, you realize that this is a bug from 2009 that talks about a feature (Amazon ads) that hasn't existed since 2009 right?

Comment: I know it's old (found it from [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/133918/167443)), but I figured it was just the standard ads on the site.