# Bug tag cleanup

Tags: discussion, meta, unanswered-questions

There are [over two thousand questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=[bug]+answers%3A0+closed%3A0) on Meta Stack Exchange tagged [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) that have no answers (and haven't been closed). This doesn’t include *all* unresolved bugs, just the ones that haven’t had *any answers at all*.

[image: [bug] answers:0 closed:0; 2,251 results]

Some of these look like they may have been resolved by changes that have been made since they were posted ([such as by the recent changes to reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93050)), but are still here as noise, burying other issues that are potentially more serious (such as those that [prevent a user from participating fully](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/106930), or [from logging in at all](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/113875)).

It’s obvious that this tag needs to be cleaned up. Issues that have been addressed don’t indicate that, and issues that haven’t been addressed are buried under all the noise.

Is there anyone at Stack Exchange whose job it is to monitor bug reports, or will it be up to the community to go through and answer all these questions (though most of us can do nothing about the status tags)?

Comment: `UPDATE POSTS SET STATUS=DECLINED WHERE TAG=BUG AND ANSWERS=0 AND POST_DATE < TODAY-1 YEAR;`

Comment: lyk dis if u "so what" evrytim .. 5eva

Comment: @RobertHarvey not STATUS=BYDESIGN? Let's at least claim it's a feature, not a bug.

Comment: Let's fill the meta flag queue to the size of the SO main flag queue! Mission acquired, commence operation...

Comment: @RobertHarvey I don't that would work (based on the Data.SE) it would be `UPDATE posts 
SET    Tags = Tags + ' status-declined' 
WHERE  id IN (SELECT id 
              FROM   Posts q 
              WHERE  answerCount = 0 
                     AND PostTypeId = 1 
                     AND tags LIKE '%bug%' 
                     AND tags NOT LIKE '%status%' 
                     AND Datediff(y, creationDate, Getdate()) >= 1) `

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter: I knew someone would come along and declare my pseudo-SQL invalid. :P

Comment: @RobertHarvey wait... you actually expected a meta.SO user to come a long and suck all the fun out of a comment by responding with a technical clarification. You're pretty jaded. ;)

Answer (score 7):

We need a rather organized way to do this. I went through a whole bunch of posts, and answered some. But it's a big task and we need to work together here.

Here are some points I've sketched out:

1) If the question has been fixed, answer (with evidence), and flag for  [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

2) If there is a dupe, give it a close vote and try to get more CVs. We can add a CW post below this where we list stuff that needs CVs (and whoever casts the fifth/binding CV must remove it from the list). Chat also works, but it may become unwieldy.

Answer (score 3):

Please do not vote blindly, go through the post first.

**If you cast the 5th/binding vote, please remove it from here.**

#### Bugs needing close votes

[Upvotes above your rep cap disappear from your Reputation view](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96204/upvotes-above-your-rep-cap-disappear-from-your-reputation-view)