# Hover text for the moderator-only-tag explanation is improperly escaping the ♦ symbol

Tags: bug, status-completed, meta, moderator-tags, character-escaping

Hover text for the moderator-only-tag explanation is improperly escaping the ♦ symbol:

[image]

This happens on all Meta sites which have this explaination, including MSO, per site metas, Stack Apps and Area51 Discussion Zone.

Comment: I know this title is funnier, but that actually was a useful edit to the question title =)

Comment: Really, @Jim, you're going to roll back Anna Lear's rollback?

Comment: Meh, I like the title, and it seems like a decent way to get some attention to the issue (and hopefully thin out [this list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/133918/167443))

Comment: It is a funnier title, but the extra eyeballs it draws are likely to belong to people who just want a laugh and don't care about the bug. And since it doesn't describe the problem at all, it makes future searching harder. But those points aside, I got the impression this was an instance of an Official Person taking an Official Action. @Jim

Comment: I suppose you're right.

Answer (score 7):

This'll be fixed in the next deploy.

Comment: As of today (2012, Nov 02) this bug still occurs here on meta...