# Is there an effort to close old, "status-complete" questions? Should there be?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

In the [review](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/) tool here on Meta SO I'm seeing a *lot* of questions in the Close queue with the reason "Too localized" and the apparent reason is because it's a bug or feature request that has been tagged [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

Is there an effort underway by one or more people to go back and close these?

Should there be? There is a perception that Closed questions are "no good" and unwanted; I don't think these should be thought of that way. Aren't Closed questions at risk for Deletion, since they are easier to delete?

What about if a bug returns, or a feature request isn't working the way it should? Wouldn't we want to update the existing Question and/or its Answers?

By and large they seem to be older questions. Is there a guideline for how old they should be to close?

Comment: Also, these posts could explain _why_ a feature was added.

Comment: Yea, I think questions with `status-completed` tag should be protected from close votes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Should there be?

No. "Too Localized" gets misused everywhere, but the usage here on Meta is particularly ironic: *everything* is extremely localized, ***because it's a Q&A site on the topic of our Q&A sites.***

Questions that are completely obsolete, addressing situations long ago resolved with no discussion or debate and nothing that can possibly ever help another human being... Should be closed as Too Localized. Or just deleted.

Questions that address specific bugs/features/scenarios should be tagged [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) once resolved, but unless *very* obscure and *utterly* uninformative should be left around.

Comment: I will be more assiduous in my "Do Not Close" clicks, then. You might want to have a look at the recently closed "status-completed" questions to see if someone needs to be educated.

Comment: All good answers, but this is the most "official".

Answer (score 8):

I don't see any reason to close completed bugs or feature requests. The [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) tag is the proper way to distinguish those posts. Just because the bug is fixed or the feature implemented doesn't mean the question should be closed.

Besides preventing users to e.g. add an answer that shows that a bug reoccured, closing all those posts as too localized after they are marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) is just pointless additional work, it doesn't gain us anything.

Answer (score 4):

There's not an effort specifically target at closing these questions (since [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) is a resolution), but there *is* an [effort to clean up the list of bugs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/133918/167443) that are unanswered to make it easier to find things that have not yet been addressed (since they are currently mixed in with quite a few resolved issues that should be closed or tagged [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)).

Answer (score 3):

Closing [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) question *in general* is a bad idea, but there are some that don't have lasting value. The easiest example is a short-lived or minor bug report -- nobody really needs to know if reputation counts were inaccurate for one hour, six months ago, or that some obscure alt text was double-encoded. Searching on meta can be a pain and it's useful to be able to filter out these useless posts (either because they end up deleted or by adding `closed:0` to my query). The threads shouldn't be closed immediately because the issue might not actually be resolved, but if a bug recurs much later a new post can just be made.

A related type of question that I sometimes vote to close are those related to a feature that used to exist, but doesn't anymore. There are tons of questions on meta that have outdated information, but it isn't always obvious which they are. Closing these as "Too Localized" helps indicate that this information may not still be relevant. I agree that deletion is excessive in these cases; it's interesting to read about the history, and closing should serve as enough of a warning.

If users agree with this in general, it could be formalized into something that's easier to understand: how about adding an "Obsolete" close reason on meta?

Comment: I'd hope to see a comment on the question saying "this feature doesn't exist anymore" or the like, but by and large I'm not. Perhaps questions with moderator-only tags should only be close-able by Moderators.

Answer (score 2):

If the intention is close them as too localised, and then to delete them, I would say it is wrong.

If those questions received negative attentions, such as users with a reputation higher than 100 writing in an answer a complaint about how a bug has been fixed, then I would close the questions just to avoid such answers, but I would not delete them.

I don't think those questions would be closed, but if I were to decide which questions should be closed as too localised, I would close those questions for which there isn't an answer that explains why the bug happened, how the feature has been implemented, how the code worked before the change, and why the code didn't work in the specific case. For example, a bug report about a phrase not using the plural could be closed as too localised.

If we are going to close those [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) questions, then we should close those [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) questions too, but I think that those questions contain important information too.

Comment: A bug report about a phrase not using the plural would more likely be closed as a duplicate. Or deleted by the asker to avoid [Jeff's wrath](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9694/167443)

Comment: I am not sure it would be closed as duplicate. Anyway, it was just an example of questions for which there isn't much explanation about how it is fixed, how the code worked before, and why the code didn't used the correct plural. There could be eventually an explanation why what reported as bug is not a bug, and why not using the plural is correct in the described case; if there is such explanation, the bug report would probably be tagged as [meta-tag:status-bydesign], or [meta-tag:status-declined], not [meta-tag:status-completed].